# Apache mod_rewrite: HTTPS is always off when rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I'm attempting to rewrite a whole site to HTTPS, with one exception going through plain HTTP.

No matter what I do, the `%{HTTPS}` seems to always be `off` and the `%{SERVER_PORT}` is always `80`. Even when I'm succesfully accessing the site through `https://...`. Dumping the `$_SERVER` global in PHP shows the correct values (HTTPS is `on` and such).

When does `mod_rewrite` actually know the value of those server variables, or is my server configuration broken some way?

I've used `LogLevel debug rewrite:trace6` to look for issues, and it seems that the server thinks HTTPS is never enabled.

I have two virtual hosts, one for 80-traffic and one for 443-traffic. Is it possible that my `.htaccess` rewrite rules are not properly read within the 443 virtual host?

Can self-signed certificates create issues like these? I can access the site fine once I accept a "risky" certificate for each session.

I'm running Apache 2.4+, php5-fpm and the site is WordPress multisite. Here is my current `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.dev
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/nohttps.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.dev/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ # This line never matches according to logs.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.dev
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/nohttps.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.dev/$1 [L,R=301]

# WordPress' own rules onwards.

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Because the second `%{SERVER_PORT}` **never** matches (80 != 443), all `example.dev/nohttps` requests are rewritten with `. index.php [L]`, which redirects them to the homepage.

Additionally I've set `UseCanonicalPhysicalPort` to `on` in both virtual host.

Comment: Could be related to self-signed certificates...

Comment: Could be a bit late for you, but I just ran into a similar issue. It was because Apache was behind a load balancer (managed VPS), and I needed to use this rule : `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https` instead of testing port 443 or `%{HTTPS}` value

Comment: I know it looks stupid, but users that run into this problem should make sure there isn't other HTTP server that on the same host that does https instead of Apache. I've found nginx + Apache configurations where nginx were setup to deliver static content over HTTPS but I discovered that only after trying to use HTTPS on my website.